# c++20 library support for xcode 12

Tags: c++, xcode, c++20, xcode12, xcode12beta5

can i use the c++20 library with xcode 12? (xcode 12 beta 5, with clang version 10.0.0).

so in xcode build settings, instead of

```
// in xcode build settings, "c++ standard library"
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libc++
```

maybe use something like (does not work => clang err: invalid library name)

```
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libc++20 // eg. libc++20 & libc++2a are invalid names
```

i have already set (works by providing c++20 *language* support, but does not provide c++20 *library* support)

```
// in xcode build settings, "c++ language dialect"
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = c++2a // ok but does not provide c++20 library
```

im aware that the c++20 library is not yet complete/officially released.

question:

do you know of any (easy) way to use the (preliminary) c++20 library with xcode 12?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can be easier ways, or I might have done something redundant (let me know what can be removed), but here's a surefire way.

If you download the LLVM binaries from LLVM releases, do Step 1 - a and not Step 1 - b.

#### Step 1 - a

Download the LLVM + Clang binaries of your choice.

- https://releases.llvm.org/
- https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases

Copy the toolchain from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain` and paste it in `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains`.

Right click -> Show package Contents.

- Change the identifier in `ToolchainInfo.plist` file to what you want "MyAmazingToolchain".
- Replace all the bin include lib libexec folders with what you got from LLVM.

Move on to Step 2.

#### Step 1 - b

Build llvm with

```
cmake -G "Sublime Text 2 - Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=“clang;libcxx;libcxxabi” -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -DLLVM_CCACHE_BUILD=ON -DLLVM_CREATE_XCODE_TOOLCHAIN=ON \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="easy to clean location"\
-DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=OFF \
../llvm
```

- http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html
- https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html

`libcxxabi` is required or linking `libcxx` will fail with:

> ld: library not found for -lcxxabi_shared
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

`DLLVM_CCACHE_BUILD` requires https://ccache.dev (use brew if you wish). First build will be very slow. Rebuilds will be faster.

---

After the above is done and ninja compiles around 3000 files, run

```
 ninja install all 
 ninja install-xcode-toolchain
```

Find the created toolchain in `location you chose above/Toolchains`. Copy it to `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains/`

---

#### Step 2

If Xcode is open, close it and reopen. In Xcode app menu > Toolchains > choose the new one, llvm12git.

Create a new c++ project normally and go to its project's build settings.

Search for `COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE` or `Enable index-while-building functionality` and set it to "No". Otherwise, build fails with "unrecognised option" about indexing.

---

#### Step 3

Change "C++ language dialect" to "c++20" or "c++2a"

[image]

Build the project normally. However, warnings may not go away while the code successfully builds due to indexing disabled. :( Adding header search path helps with warnings.

- [Adding system header search path to Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428216/adding-system-header-search-path-to-xcode)

---

Make sure to check feature status:

- http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20

Code I tested:

```
#include <compare>
#include <concepts>

struct Aggr {
  int i;
  char c;

  auto operator<=>(Aggr const &) const = default;
};
struct A {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};
int main()
{

  // A a{.y = 2,.x = 1};  // error; designator order does not match declaration
  // order
  A b{.x = 1, .z = 2};  // ok, b.y initialized to 0
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I have to add that `ninja install build-xcode-toolchain` didn't make the Toolchains folder, the command `ninja install-xcode-toolchain` did. (As taken from https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-703.0.29/src/tools/xcode-toolchain/CMakeLists.txt.auto.html)

Comment: thanks. Although you should be checking https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/tools/xcode-toolchain/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I get "The toolchain is not compatible with this version of Xcode." when choosing `MyAmazingToolchain` in XCode Toolchains (I did not change any binaries in `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/`) using XCode 13.4.