# ld: unknown option: -platform_version when building R packages from source

Tags: r, clang, ld

Certain R packages, such as `mgcv`, fail to compile from source with clang 10+ (under macOS 10.14 and R version 3.6+). The error reported during compilation is

```
ld: unknown option: -platform_version
```

How do I resolve this error and compile these packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `ld` is the same as in [Clang 10 fails to link C++ application with CMake on macOS 10.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934005/clang-10-fails-to-link-c-application-with-cmake-on-macos-10-12). However, the suggestion to add the flag `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-mlinker-version=305"` is not applicable to the R package compilation process. For R, you need to add `-mlinker-version=305` to `LDFLAGS` to your `Makevars` file, typically located in `$HOME/.R/`.

My `Makevars` is based on [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/btskinner/98f0501ceb21e1c8e7ff9dbaa5bf7b96). I changed `LDFLAGS` from this:

```
LDFLAGS+=-L$(HO)/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(HO)/llvm/lib
```

to this:

```
LDFLAGS+=-L$(HO)/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(HO)/llvm/lib -mlinker-version=305
```

That resolved the `ld` error when compiling `mgcv` from source.

For the `igraph` package, adding the `mlinker` flag to `LDFLAGS` was not enough; it had to be added to the C++ flags as well. In the gist `Makevars` above, this is done by adding `-mlinker-version=305` to `STD_FLAGS`, which then adds the flag to `CXX**FLAGS` for all C++ versions.

UPDATE, June 24 2020: unfortunately, some packages (rJava in my case) fail to use the `STD_FLAGS`. My workaround was to put the mlinker flag in the C compiler invocation:

```
CC=$(CCACHE) $(HO)/llvm/bin/clang -mlinker-version=305
```